# Raspberrypi camera image and python socket communication

Tags: android, raspbian

l want to send image file for android studio. but it did't work well;
this problem is this image is jpeg file. but android studio is work only url.

```
public void onBtnLoad1() {

   // Uri imgUri=Uri.parse("////192.168.0.8//pi//newimage.jpg");
    //ImageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg")));
    String addr = "file://192.168.0.8/pi/newimage.jpg";
    //ImageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg").toString()));

    new HttpReqTask().execute(addr);
}
```

what is the problem here?

Comment: Is the url @ file://192.168.0.8/pi/newimage.jpg accessible to you?

Comment: yes! this jpg file is open in my computer and raspberrypi!(connection server is sambaserver)

Comment: `want to send image file for android studio`. ?? Unclear who is sending. From where?  And to whom. Could you start telling that? And who is using python? What has Android Studio to do with it?

Comment: server language is python. python is socket communication from android ip. then, raspbeerrypi camera take a picture. and store raspberrypi image folder. l want this image viewer.

Comment: Well sorry.. If you are unable to give decent information i cannot help you.